# Error Panel Row Updating

Tags: c#

I want to show error panel on row updating but it does not show the error panel. What's wrong with this code?

```
protected void Grades_GridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{  
    string LetterGrade = Grades_GridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["Letter_Grade"].ToString();
    TextBox txtMinGrade = (TextBox)Grades_GridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtMinGrade");
    TextBox txtMaxGrade = (TextBox)Grades_GridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtMaxGrade");

    if (Convert.ToDecimal(txtMinGrade.Text) > Convert.ToDecimal(txtMaxGrade.Text))
    {
        PanelError.Visible = true;
        LabelErrorString.Text = "Minimum grade must not be greater than maximum grade!";     
    }
    else
    {
        Admin.updateGradeRanges(LetterGrade, txtMinGrade.Text, txtMaxGrade.Text);
    }
    Grades_GridView.EditIndex = -1;
    FillGradeRangesInGrid();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping through that code in the debugger? If the text box doesn't contain a valid number, `Convert.ToDecimal()` will throw an exception. Could that be happening? Also, if `txtMinGrade` or `txtMaxGrade` are for some reason, you'll get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: I do necessary controls but it does not show the error panel how should I display error if min grade > max grade in gridview